# Switch statement fails in nested type

Tags: java

I have the following switch:

My groupPosition is 0 and childPosition is 1:

```
switch (groupPosition) {
            case 0:
                switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        if (NetworkManager.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
                            new UserAwayTask().execute();
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Network not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        selection = null;
                        selectionArgs = null;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selection = Employee.COL_COUNTRY + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                        selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
                }
            case 1:
                selection = Employee.COL_DEPARTMENT + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
                break;
            case 2:
                empIDList = GetAllTeamLeaders.teamLeaders(this, TeamLeader.COL_TEAMMEMBERID, TeamLeader.COL_TEAMLEADERNAME + " IS ? ", new String[]{valueReceived});
                selection = Employee.COL_EMPID + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(empIDList.size(), "?")) + ")";
                selectionArgs = empIDList.toArray(new String[empIDList.size()]);
                break;
        }
```

But each time my selection is: department IS ? COLLATE NOCASE
and selection args is from case 1 from the outer switch.

So this:

```
 case 1:
                selection = Employee.COL_DEPARTMENT + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
                break;
```

is getting executed instead of :

```
case 2:
                        selection = Employee.COL_COUNTRY + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                        selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
```

However if I comment the outer switch's case 1 and case 2. I get the desired result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing a break statement for case 0:

Comment: You need a semicolon and a `break` after the `switch` statement in `case 0` or it will drop through to `case 1` when it completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a `break` for the top-level `case 0`:

```
case 0:
    switch (childPosition) {
        case 0:
            if (NetworkManager.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
                new UserAwayTask().execute();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case 1:
            selection = null;
            selectionArgs = null;
            break;
        case 2:
            selection = Employee.COL_COUNTRY + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
            break;
    }
break; //¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Without the `break;`, the flow just proceeds and enters the next `case` block until it reaches a `break` statement (or until it goes out of the `switch`).

Also, it's not bad idea to add a `break` for the nested `case 2` (just in case you add more `case`s in the future and you might end up with the same problem as this one, which by the way is called *fall-through*).

Comment: I missed that! Funk! Thanks mate

Comment: Fall-Through, I cant express in words how thankful I am to you :)

Answer (score 3):

Your are missing a break:

```
switch (groupPosition) {
    case 0:
        switch (childPosition) {
            ...
        }
        break; // <-- here
    case 1:
        selection = Employee.COL_DEPARTMENT + " IS ? COLLATE NOCASE";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{valueReceived};
        break;
    case 2:
        empIDList = GetAllTeamLeaders.teamLeaders(this, TeamLeader.COL_TEAMMEMBERID, TeamLeader.COL_TEAMLEADERNAME + " IS ? ", new String[]{valueReceived});
        selection = Employee.COL_EMPID + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(empIDList.size(), "?")) + ")";
        selectionArgs = empIDList.toArray(new String[empIDList.size()]);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not break from your outer switch case 0. Add a `break` at the closing bracket of your inner switch.

```
case 0:
    switch (childPosition) {
    //
    } break;
```